# Ubuntu 20.04 20.10 freezes with artifacts on screen intel uhd 630 graphics

Tags: drivers, 20.04, intel-graphics, freeze, 20.10

Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10, Dell Latitude 5510

This problem seems to occur at random, sometimes once in few days, sometimes multiple times a day. Ubuntu freezes completely, no input is possible, only restart by power button is working. There is no indication in logs about what's wrong. I have checked disk, memory.

drivers should be the latest:

```
lshw -C video

*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:169 memory:cb000000-cbffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I'm using external display to extend workspace, connected by HDMI

any ideas about what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a *complete* answer, but the issue could also be related to the SSD in the machine. I've seen a number of Dell Latitude units at work show similar halting/freezing issues over the years and it has often been due to an out-dated SSD/NVMe firmware.

You can check which firmware your device is using with `nvme`. You will likely need to install it first, though:

0. Install the necessary software: `sudo apt install nvme-cli`
1. List the NVMe devices in the machine: `sudo nvme list`

For my machine, I see this:

```
Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1     S359NX0K103156       SAMSUNG MZVLW512HMJP-000L7               1         236.49  GB / 512.11  GB    512   B +  0 B   7L7QCXY7
```

Compare the `FW Rev` number with the most recent version from Dell. If it matches, also look for updated firmware [on their site](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-15-5510-laptop/drivers). From what I can see, it looks like there's an updated BIOS available. This *may* have appeared in your "Software Updates" application as something to look at.

You can also check for firmware updates with `sudo fwupdmgr update`. You should see something like this:

```
• Thunderbolt Controller has the latest available firmware version
• SAMSUNG MZVLW512HMJP-000L7 has the latest available firmware version
• System Firmware has the latest available firmware version
Upgrade available for UEFI Device Firmware from 184.79.3722 to 184.80.3746
20HQCTO1WW must remain plugged into a power source for the duration of the update to avoid damage. Continue with update? [Y|n]:
```

Incidentally, it seems my notebook has some updates available. This is a good way to ensure maximum efficiency of your devices.

Comment: 'sadly' it looks that the firmware for nvme is up to date